# dynamic change of script tag is not reflecting on content of the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

App.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
   let listen = history.listen((location)=>{
    let element1 = document.getElementById('chatBot-1');
    let element2 = document.getElementById('chatBot-2');
      element1 && element1.remove();
      element2 && element2.remove();

    const script = document.createElement("script");

    if(window.location.pathname.includes('/covid19'))
      script.id="chatBot-1"

    else
      script.id="chatBot-2"

  script.src = script_target_url;
  // script.defer = true; -- Didn't helped
  //script.async = true;  -- Didn't helped
  document.body.appendChild(script);

 })
}, []);
```

As shown above, It is App.jsx of our application. we are trying to load two different scripts on certain conditions by injecting and detecting the route change. The route detection happens correctly.

But, what I observed. The script with id 'chatBot-1' and 'chatBot-2' is getting displayed on the expected url in the html page under the elements section in the browser console.

But the content of the page on view layer is not getting changed.

Need your expert help/opinion, Thanks in advance.